# Android Studio 3 can't build my project

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using Android Studio 3 preview to code and build a android kotlin project but it does not seem to compile due to this error:

> : java.lang.Exception: Unable to get response from daemon in 10000 ms
>
> Could not perform incremental compilation: Could not connect to Kotlin
>   compile daemon Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback
>   strategy.
>
> ```
> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause:
> Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
> ```

Here is my gradle build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jr.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        buildConfigField "String", "DEMO_SERVER_URL", "https://demoserver.restlet.net/v1/"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you can retry the build by killing the gradle daemon first (`gradlew --stop`), then if still doesn't work, compile again with `--info` and/or `--debug` and/or `--stacktrace` (ie `gradlew build --info`)

Comment: tried that and still fails to build the project with the same error

Comment: Have you tried to build your project under command line? `./gradlew build`

Comment: I had this same problem with Kotlin in IntelliJ IDEA, but not AS. To solve it there, I unchecked "Keep compiler process alive between invocations" in File->Settings->Other Settings->Kotlin Compiler.

Comment: Does your problem still persist if you update to the latest stable version? If so, I would suggest you close down this question or even write the solution if you found any.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the same error I had. 
I solved [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/broken-compilation-in-ide/1377)

Answer (score 0):

Try to close android studio, delete .gradle and then open it. I had the same problem and it's fixed now.